# Skip "Use network mirror?" in debian preseed

Tags: debian, preseed

I'm trying to automatically install debian wheezy. In my preseed file, I have set

```
apt-mirror-setup apt-setup/no_mirror boolean false
```

Nevertheless, I get this annoying question:
[image: "Use a network mirror?" Yes|No]

How do I turn it off and always activate a network mirror?

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two very similar options. You want

```
apt-mirror-setup apt-setup/use_mirror boolean true
```